# Activejob fails deserializing an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

To test that my mails are being sent I'm running `heroku run rails c -a my_app`. Then I enqueue the job and it is enqueued fine. However, when I go to Redis and see queued jobs the job is not there. Instead, it is on "retry".

This is what I see:

`{"retry":true,"queue":"default","class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","args":[{"job_class":"SendMailJob","job_id":"4b4ba46f-94d7-45cd-b923-ec1678c73076","queue_name":"default","arguments":["any_help",{"_aj_globalid":"gid://gemfeedapi/User/546641393834330002000000"}]}],"jid":"f89235d7ab19f605ed0461a1","enqueued_at":1424175756.9351726,"error_message":"Error while trying to deserialize arguments: \nProblem:\n  Document(s) not found for class User with id(s) 546641393834330002000000.\nSummary:\n  When calling User.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): 546641393834330002000000 ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: 546641393834330002000000.\nResolution:\n  Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.","error_class":"ActiveJob::DeserializationError","failed_at":1424175773.317896,"retry_count":0}`

However, object is in the Database.

I've tried to add `after_create` callback (Mongoid) but doesn't make any difference.

Any idea on what is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sidekiq is so fast that it executes your job before the database has committed the transaction.  Use `after_commit` to create the job.

Comment: @mike_perham Please read my question. I already tried that (using Mongoid though): http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html

Comment: Please read my comment.  :-)  after_commit is not after_create.

Comment: I know, but Mongoid does not have that callback (after_commit).

Comment: this is not correct. it's not about being Sidekiq being fast. It happens so because after_commit fires after the transaction has completed

Comment: Sidekiq's speed makes the race condition much more apparent.

Comment: "Use after_commit to create the job." How and where please?

Comment: Best ever reason for a failure! Great to know.

Comment: @AdrianMann use after_commit in your model, where you would normally use after_create

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my fault. You need to start a new Heroku Worker Dyno in order to make Sidekiq work (it doesn't do it automatically).